# Nodejs express wait until response or action from another endpoint

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 endpoints: writeToFile and removeFromFile. writeToFile simply writes a dummy json. removeFromFile tries to remove that dummy json field previously written by writeToFile.

On the client side the user can only call the removeFromFile after he has called the writeToFile endpoint. As writeToFile takes 8 seconds the user can click the button that triggers the api call to removeFromFile before that json has been written. Therefore, removeFromFile needs to wait until the dummy json has been written before trying to remove the field.

I achieve that by using a setTimeout with a hardcoded time. However, how can I do that using promises or callbacks?

This is my code:

```js
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const server = express();

class FileController {
    static async removeFromFile(req, res, next) {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            // read from file and remove from file and if success
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            });
        }, 20000)
    }

    static async writeToFile(req, res, next) {
        try {
            const fileId = await new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>resolve("1234"),8000));
            fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./config/fileIds.json"), JSON.stringify({foo: fileId}));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(
                new Error("Something went wrong when writing to file ...")
            );
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
        });
    }
}

server.get("/writeToFile", FileController.writeToFile)
server.get("/removeFromFile", FileController.removeFromFile)

const port = 8083;
server.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("Server running on port ", port)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two different solutions. One using event emitters and another one using setInterval.

- In the events solution I set a timeout to send a response to the user after 20 seconds in case it's not triggered by the emitter.
  I also consume the event inside the res.on("finish"...) from writeToFile to not consume it in the removeFromFile because the main purpose of removeFromFile is to remove the file before writeToFile finishes.
- In the setInterval solution I use a boolean once it's written and then a setInterval to check the status until it's updated. The maxTimer is set to stop the setInterval and give a response to the user after 20 seconds.

events solution:

```js
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express");
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const server = express();

const event = new EventEmitter();
const timers = [];

class FileController {
    static async removeFromFile(req, res, next) {
        const filePath = req.body.filePath;
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            event.emit("isWritten", true);
            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false
            });
        }, 20000)
        timers.push(timer);

        event.once("isWritten", (exit) => {
            while (timers.length > 0) {
                const time = timers.pop();
                clearTimeout(time);
            }
            if (exit) return;
            // read from file and remove from file and if success
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            });
        })
    }

    static async writeToFile(req, res, next) {
        const filePath = req.body.filePath;
        const fileId = req.body.fileId;
        const waitTime = req.body.waitTime;
        try {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), waitTime));
            const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./config/fileIds.json")).toString());
            json[filePath] = fileId;
            fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./config/fileIds.json"), JSON.stringify(json));
            event.emit("isWritten", false);
            res.on("finish", async () => {
                event.once("isWritten", () => {})
                // read from file and remove from file
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(
                new Error("Something went wrong when writing to file ...")
            );
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
        });
    }
}

server.get("/writeToFile", FileController.writeToFile)
server.get("/removeFromFile", FileController.removeFromFile)

const port = 8083;
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port ", port)
})
```

setInterval solution:

```js
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const server = express();

class FileController {
    static isWritten = false;
    static async removeFromFile(req, res, next) {
        let maxTimer = 20;
        let timer = 1;
        const interval = setInterval(()=>{
            timer += 1;
            if(timer === maxTimer){
                clearInterval(interval);
                return res.status(400).json({
                    success: false
                });
            }
            if(FileController.isWritten){
                clearInterval(interval);
                // read from file and remove from file and if success
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true
                });
            }
        },1000);
    }

    static async writeToFile(req, res, next) {
        FileController.isWritten = false;
        try {
            const fileId = await new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>resolve("1234"),8000));
            fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./config/fileIds.json"), JSON.stringify({foo: fileId}));
            FileController.isWritten = true;
            res.on("finish", async () => {
             // read from file and remove from file
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(
                new Error("Something went wrong when writing to file ...")
            );
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
        });
    }
}

server.get("/writeToFile", FileController.writeToFile)
server.get("/removeFromFile", FileController.removeFromFile)

const port = 8083;
server.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("Server running on port ", port)
})
```